# Projection transformation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I appear to be having problems with re-projecting a bunch of shapefiles that are set to project at WGS_1984_Complex_UTM_Zone_28N coordinate system into Sierra_Leone_1968_UTM_Zone_28N.

I am using the "Project" tool from the Geoprocessing tools to get them into the right projection however after this process is complete the features in my shapefiles are offset. I'm unsure how to correct this, as ArcMap appears to calculate this by default. Does anyone know of a custom transformation that might help with my offsetting issue?

Comment: Are you using a geographic (datum) transformation in ArcMap? Are you using the same one(s) in the Project tool?

Comment: probably ArcMap can not find the right transformation that's why your points are offset. Try to find another projection system that ArcMap finds a transformation automatically then reproject.

Answer (score 0):

If they are not aligned when you keep them in their coordinates systems and use 'on the fly projection', it might be one of the layers, rather than the re-projection that it is the problem.

I'm not sure how to adjust layers if so - but there must be a way to offest them.

Comment: I'm trying not to manually offset them - "on the fly" they seem to sit in the correct place but once they are reprojected they get offset from where the features sat initially. Is there a way to calc a transformation myself rather than doing a manual "move" of features?

Comment: I'm not sure where the offset is coming from then. Does the offset still appear if you "save as" the layer in a new projection?